# How to write a PHP coding to list out all files and directories as links to them?

Tags: php

This is somewhat similar to some index pages. When new file or folder is added to the directory, HTML page should display the newly created file/folder together with previous ones after it is being refreshed. (prefer in alphabatical order)

How to achieve this sort of functionality in PHP? Please provide sample coding as well. (and any references)

Answer (score 17):

this is rather easy, here you go:

```
$files = scandir('./directory/to/list');
sort($files); // this does the sorting
foreach($files as $file){
   echo'<a href="/directory/to/list/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
}
```

this should give you a basic idea what to do.

Comment: PHP's directory read functions automatically sort (note the optional sort_order parameter for `scandir`), so no need to `sort` again.

Comment: Adding `$files = array_diff(($files), array('.', '..'));` before the foreach statement strips out `.` and `..` from the rendered html

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much a direct rip from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dir.php):

```
<?php
$d = dir(".");
echo "Path: " . $d->path . "\n";
echo "<ul>";
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
   echo "<li><a href='{$entry}'>{$entry}</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
$d->close();
?>
```