# Recursively generate a list of links to all files, directories and subdirectories with PHP

Tags: php

It is easy to [list all files and directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294266/how-to-write-a-php-coding-to-list-out-all-files-and-directories-as-links-to-them) within a particular directory.

How would one do the same task recursively? That is, starting from a given directory, generate a list of links to all files and directories including those in subfolders at every level of the directory tree? For example:

- `mydir\`
- `mydir\file.php`
- `mydir\sub1\`
- `mydir\sub1\file2.php`
- `mydir\sub1\sub2\`
- `mydir\sub1\sub2\file3.php`
- `mydir\sub3\`

…and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to the pretty much the same (either by using the dir class or the opendir function).
However, instead of just running 1 directoy with it, make a function that does exactly that. Then, within that function, you use the `filetype()` function to check whether the the current item in the iteration is a directory, and run the function itself on that directory again, thus making what's called a **recursive function**.

Now, just start the function of the base directory you'll want to list, and it will go through all subdirectories as you want it.

Common mistakes:

- Make sure you catch and exclude "." and ".." directories.
- Make sure you append slashes on the recursive calls, so your path is correct.

**Edit:**
Actually, DanFromGermany's answer above is pretty good. **If** you're willing to rely on the underlying OS functions and **if** you know that your script will always be used on Unix/Linux/BSD systems that have `find`, you'll want to use that one.

Comment: Thx for mentioning. I'm actually not sure wether `find` relies on `updatedb`, tho.. which means one would have to update the index db quite often. But I think this is only important for `locate`.

Answer (score 0):

**Pseudo** code:

```
<?php
$target  = './files/';
$exclude = array(
    $target,
    'secret_file.jpg',
);
$files   = explode(PHP_EOL, exec('find ' . $target));
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (!in_array($file, $exclude)
     && !in_array(str_replace($target, $file), $exclude) {
        echo '<a href="' . $file . '>' . $file . '</a>';
    }
}
```

(works for linux, if `exec` is enabled)

`exec('find ./files/')` gives you output like this:

```
[root@giant.flowl.info]# find ./cron/
./cron/
./cron/cron.php
./cron/temp/session.tmp
./cron/temp/test/temp.jpg
```